# Android code to add and view data through application

Tags: android

I am developing a Task manager( a simple one) to learn android and this is my short description.
I am making two activities one to view task and other to add ( and I am using an Application class through which i add the task)..
when i add the task on the addtask activity my viewtask activity still remains blank. Could you help me out.
This is my viewTask activity.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_task);
        setupviews();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        System.out.println(requestCode);
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            showtask(); // your "refresh" code
        }
    }

    public void OnResume()
    {
         super.onResume();       
         System.out.println("Its working...");
         showtask();
    }

    /*public void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
    }*/

   public void showtask()
   {
        ArrayList<Task> task=gettma().gettask();
        StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer();
        for(Task t:task){
            sb.append(String.format("* %s\n", t.toString()));
            System.out.println("Its working...again");
        }
        taskText.setText(sb.toString());

        }

   private TaskManagerApplication gettma() {
        TaskManagerApplication tma1=(TaskManagerApplication)getApplication();
        return tma1;
    }
    private void setupviews() {

        AddButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.AddButton);
        taskText=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextList);
        AddButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                 Intent intent=new Intent(ViewTask.this,AddTask.class);              
                 startActivity(intent);             

            }
        });
    }
}
```

And this is my Addtask activity.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.addtask);
        setupviews();
    }

    protected void addtask() {
        String name=EditText.getText().toString();
        Task t= new Task(name);
        //System.out.println("its working here");
        gettma().addTask(t);
        finish();
    }

    private TaskManagerApplication gettma() {
        TaskManagerApplication tma=(TaskManagerApplication)getApplication();
        return tma;
    }
    private void setupviews() {
        EditText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText);
        AddButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.AddButton1);
        CancelButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.CancelButton);
        AddButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            addtask();

            }
        });
        CancelButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();

            }
        });

    }


}
```

Please Help

Comment: Quite frankly, adding a couple of screenshots would have been better than posting a morass of code. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
EditText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText);
```

This is the line in your `setupviews()`. You cannot do this because `EditText` is a class and you need a variable of that type to which you can assign a value. It must be `EditText` followed by some variable name.

```
if (requestCode == 1) {
            showtask(); // your "refresh" code
}
```

This is in your `onActivityResult()`. You aren't checking the `resultCode` to check if the called `Activity` failed to do the operation that would produce a result.

Also, in numerous places you arent following the Java naming convention. Please, use upper and lower cases properly when naming variables and classes.